# Find missing minute data in time series data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series data that has data for each minute, but due to some problems in sensor, sometimes the data is not fetched and that minute data is not recorded. I want to find on which day and on which hour this happened. I have the data in pandas dataframe. This is my code snippet to store in data frame, I would like to display which minute data wasn't received.

```
l=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=l)
k=0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    db=client.test
    collection=db['data']
    cursor = collection.find({"deviceId":3},{"timestamp":1,"cd":1}).sort("timestamp",-1).limit(1000)
    for document in cursor:
        for key,value in document.items()[1:-1]:
            df.loc[k,'Year']=2017
            df.loc[k,'Month']=value.month
            df.loc[k,'Day']=value.day
            df.loc[k,'Hour']=value.hour
            df.loc[k,'Minute']=value.minute
            k=k+1
    minute_a = pd.Series(np.arange(0, 60))
```

I was thinking to use `isin` function using `minute_a` but as every hour I have to check, I can't figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.isin.html) would be good way of doing this. However, the easiest way of doing this would be to flatten your sensor time data into a single `DatetimeIndex` so you can compare it with a reference `DatetimeIndex`.

```
# creating reference DatetimeIndex idx_ref with a minute frequency
end=datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
dt = end - timedelta(days=1)
idx_ref = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=dt, end=end,freq='min')

# idx_dat represents your DatetimeIndex from the sensor
gaps = idx_ref[~idx_ref.isin(idx_dat)]
```

Assuming you are only interested in the time gaps of course.

Comment: pd.DatetimeIndex(start=dt, end=end, freq='min') is not longer supported. Therefore the parameters start and end got removed. You can use pd.date_range(), pd.timedelta_range(), pd.period_range() or pd.interval_range with start, end, freq instead. Answer should be updated.