# pandas asfreq() function is not showing the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the gaps in a time series( 30 min interval) and fill them with NaN.

I am referring to the instructions on this post but it turns out that the code is not performing well in my case.
[Find gaps in pandas time series dataframe sampled at 1 minute intervals and fill the gaps with new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592536/find-gaps-in-pandas-time-series-dataframe-sampled-at-1-minute-intervals-and-fill?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df=pd.read_csv('example1.csv')
df.head(5)
Date & Time KW
0   8/27/2019 23:30 0.016
1   8/27/2019 23:00 0
2   8/27/2019 22:30 0.016
3   8/27/2019 22:00 0.016
4   8/27/2019 21:30 0
df['Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date & Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df=df.set_index('Date & Time').asfreq('30M')
df.head()
    KW
Date & Time
```

As you can see the output is blank, I am expected to see values.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` is month and your 'Date & Time' column is decreasing. You need to use `T` and negative value

Try on this sample

```
df:

       Date & Time     KW
0  8/27/2019 23:30  0.016
1  8/27/2019 23:00  0.000
2  8/27/2019 22:30  0.016
3  8/27/2019 22:00  0.016
4  8/27/2019 21:30  0.000
5  8/27/2019 19:30  0.000

df.set_index('Date & Time').asfreq('-30T')

Out[412]:
                        KW
Date & Time
2019-08-27 23:30:00  0.016
2019-08-27 23:00:00  0.000
2019-08-27 22:30:00  0.016
2019-08-27 22:00:00  0.016
2019-08-27 21:30:00  0.000
2019-08-27 21:00:00 NaN
2019-08-27 20:30:00 NaN
2019-08-27 20:00:00 NaN
2019-08-27 19:30:00  0.000
```

Comment: Hey @Andy L. thank you so much. It looks like it is working. I have one last question . I am not sure of why I have to use T. In format (format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') I haven't declared anywhere.

Comment: @Verbamore: `format` using python's strftime formatting directives. While the frequency strings in  pandas time series  are pandas `Offset aliases`. They are different. You may read this docs for more info:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases